# How to shut down a node server with a shell script?

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-code-deploy

The context of this question is that I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline in AWS. I'm currently at the stage where I am creating the appspec.yml file which instructs the AWS robots on where to put my files from my new build onto my EC2 instance, as well as a list of .sh files with bash commands to stop the server, install dependencies and start the server again.

Well right off the bat I have hit a wall here. The method to shut down a node server is ctrl+c. However I have no idea how to successfully put that into bash script. And considering how many people have CI/CD pipelines setup with node servers, i'm shocked that I haven't been able to find a sample script file for this already. Does anyone have any resources on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `kill` (or it's variations like `pkill`) to send a signal to the server process and shut it down.

`kill` requires the pid of the process whereas `pkill` requires the name of the process

Comment: using kill gives me a list of modifiers for the kill command, but doesn't actually stop all processes. It would be great to to be able to name the process, but because this is all being executed programatically i'm assuming that the process id is going to change on every restart so hardwiring a process id into the script is going to fail

Comment: If you use bash, tou can use `$!`to get the pid of the last command. 
And thus you can do : `./startserver ; PID="$!"` and then 
`kill $PID`